# iOS: XMPPRoster Gets the list of Invited buddies as well

Tags: ios, xmppframework

I am building an iOS chat application using the XMPPframework. I have been able to register, send invites, accept invitation and chat. However when I try to populate my buddy list using the Roster, I get the names of all the buddies whom I have already added as well as whom I have sent Friend request. I am not able to differentiate between them. I have tried to dig into the XMPPRosterMemoryStorage class but all the methods are returning the same list (sorted/unsorted).

How to show an invited buddy as pending if he has not accepted the invitation yet.

Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my question. Looks like i didn't dig deep enough in XMPPRosterMemoryStorage class. All the jid's along with other details like subscription & ask attributes are received in Roster. However the methods sorted/unsorted were returning only the jid's of all the users. I went back and customized the XMPPRosterMemoryStorage class to return only jid's which have been accepted by both users.